# Is it possible to download SVF2 model derivatives for offline viewing?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

We are currently translating, downloading and viewing models within our application using the derivatives API, forge viewer, and targeting the SVF format.   I am exploring doing the same thing using the SVF2 format but I have found evidence that this is not supported (for various reasons).

https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/basics/preperation/
"...This means that SVF2 derivatives cannot be downloaded for offline viewing."

Wondering if this documentation is stale and this is actually possible now, or might be in the near future.  I am looking for a concrete answer on this before I explore this any further.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is NO public sample code that demonstrates how to download and view SVF2 in Forge Viewer.  Only SVF1.

For SVF2, once you have figured it out (it's not that hard to download the 1000's mesh pieces), you'll need to host these mesh bits statically via the web-socket protocol.  Finally, point Forge Viewer to your new host.

Don't forget to cache the viewer3d.min.js file, to comply with the EULA (found in the header).  Since it's a cache, you'll need to show that the device can pull this file directly from Autodesk servers, when a cache flush occurs.

That's how I would do it.

Comment: ezpz. Simply reverse engineer the undocumented proprietary binary protocol Autodesk engineers came up with. How hard can it be? A good dev will just look at the bits on the wire and infer their usage. For example "g" obviously stands for "geometry". See how easy that was? Now draw the rest the owl. /s